# Single.php different behaviour from admin to non-admin

Tags: loop, single

For the same post, I have suddenly a weird behaviour of `single.php` file between normal user and administrator.

In the beginning of the loop, I perform:

```
echo '<pre dir="ltr">';
print_r($GLOBALS['wp_query']);
echo '</pre>';
```

And the result is different.

**In the case of administrator:**

```
[queried_object_id] => 603
    [request] => SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_name = 'test' AND wp_posts.post_type = 'aya-bi-aya'  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

**In the case of non-administrator:**

```
[queried_object_id] => 0
    [request] => SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'aya-bi-aya' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

I spent one day and a half trying to figure out what can be the reason behind this dysfunctionning, but in vain. Your time is really invaluable.

Comment: Poorly written filter? `query_posts` breaking things? Perhaps the ___code for the problem page___ would help.

Comment: You really rescue many people on this earth S_HA_DUM!!. You are  right, when I isolated my sidebar (which contains query_posts many instances), the problem was resolved. Now I am going to replace query_posts. Thank you very much for your smart help. I am waiting for it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per a comment, the problem was due to the use of `query_posts` which clobbers the main query.

[Please don't use `query_posts`.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/21376)

> It should be noted that using this to **replace the main query** on a page
>   can **increase page loading times**, in worst case scenarios **more than
>   doubling the amount of work needed or more**. While easy to use, the
>   function is also **prone to confusion and problems** later on. See the
>   note further below on caveats for details.
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts (emphasis mine)

In addition, it overwrites `$wp_query` which the main Loop on the page uses.

If you need additional loops use a  new `WP_Query` object, not `query_posts`.

Comment: +1. And this is the reason that I downvote any and every answer I see that uses `query_posts()`.

Comment: Thank you S_HA_DUM. What would the Earth be like without people like you??